# Stack Overflow logo on the mobile login screen is outdated

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, ios-app, logo

When I open the Stack Exchange iOS app (v1.4.5), I notice something rather peculiar:

[image]

Compare this to:

[image]

It appears that on mobile, the stacks are overflowing too much. That is, it's using the [old logo](https://youtu.be/uipTZ2re4Uk). Perhaps the login screen should be updated to match the new logo?

Comment: [The unicorn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uipTZ2re4Uk) still didn't reach the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.4.6.

This screen has actually been frozen in time since April 4, 2014.  I'm sure we've added one or two sites to the network since then...

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Brian!